# Why is MVC attribute routing not matching this GUID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to use attribute routing.  For various reasons, one of my Guid argments required for a password reset must not be in the queryString so I've had to put it in the path. That itself isn't a problem, except for the fact that I can't get the resetToken to populate in my controller - even when it matches the controller method based on on the Route attribute I have defined.

So given this URL:

http://example.com/Account/ResetPasswordBySMS/96b7ba88-65e0-4dbc-a012-e69545a29a55/?userid=9d394579-afbb-49c4-ba21-877f4dad91fa

...would not populate "resetToken" here? (it's always null)[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your action to this:

```
[Route("~/Account/ResetPasswordBySMS/{resetToken?}")]
public ActionResult ResetPasswordBySMS(string resetToken, [FromQuery] string userId, [FromQuery] string code)
{
 var guidResetToken= new Guid(resetToken);
}
```

I tested url http://localhost:55480/Account/ResetPasswordBySMS/96b7ba88-65e0-4dbc-a012-e69545a29a55?userid=9d394579-afbb-49c4-ba21-877f4dad91fa&code=fghjk in Postman. It is working.

And it is not a good idea to mix query string with routing.I would add userId and code to routing too:

```
[Route("~/Account/ResetPasswordBySMS/{resetToken?}/{userId?}/{code?}
public ActionResult ResetPasswordBySMS(string resetToken, string userId, string code)
```

I can see the url error - slash after reset token and before ? mark. This slash should be gone.

Comment: Check my updated answer pls. And could you put a code how are calling this url.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use that approach. It has to be how I put it in my question.  I can create the URL but then a 3rd party I have no control over, appends "?code=xxx&userId=yyy"    so the URL *has* to be in that format.

Comment: I was trying to put the ID in the path because you can't have two querystrings, so I can't have `/ResetPasswordBySMS/?resetToken=x?userId=y&code=z`

Comment: You have to try url like this (don't put / after resetToken) : http://example.com/Account/ResetPasswordBySMS/96b7ba88-65e0-4dbc-a012-e69545a29a55?userid=9d394579-afbb-49c4-ba21-877f4dad91fa&code=....

Comment: I updated my answer with a tested solution. It is working in my test environment.